# Taking function from controller and placing in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've noticed my angular controller is growing and ideally should be used for passing data.

I have a function that is currently contained within my controller that is called from my HTML to calculate how many months worth of data has been displayed (within a 12 month period) and if less than 12, return the remaining as empty/no payment:

**JS:**

```
$scope.getEmptyCells = function(len){
    var emptyCells = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 12 - len; i++){
        emptyCells.push(i);
    }
    return emptyCells;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="payments in MyPayments">
        <th>{{payments.name}}</th>

        <td ng-repeat="paymentAmount in payments.Details.slice(0, 12)">
            {{ paymentAmount }}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(payments.Details.length)" class="empty">
            No Payment
        </td>            

    </tr>

</table>
```

**myNewDirective:**

```
app.directive('ngGetEmptyCells', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  template: '<td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(payments.Details.length)" class="empty">No Payment</td>',
  controller: [        
    function (len) {
      var emptyCells = [];
      console.log("ngGetEmptyCells - STARTED");
      console.log("len = " + len);
      for (var i = 0; i < 12 - len; i++) {
        emptyCells.push(i);
      }
      return emptyCells;
    }
  ]
};
});
```

MY new HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="payments in MyPayments">
        <th>{{payments.name}}</th>

        <td ng-repeat="paymentAmount in payments.Details.slice(0, 12)">
            {{ paymentAmount }}
        </td>
        <ng-get-empty-cells></ng-get-empty-cells>   

    </tr>
</table>
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8hQ3R/9/

Comment: @mpm - the question is, when i create my directive as per above, i no longer see the grey empty cells as per my example in the fiddle, thanks

Comment: Why are you declaring your directives controller as an array containing one (unnamed) function?

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck - I have been reading suggestions from other stackoverflow questions and trying different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller (in your directive) is incorrect. You can set the method `getEmptyCells` on your scope of your directive if you do it like this instead.

```
controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.getEmptyCells = function(len){
        var emptyCells = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 12 - len; i++){
            emptyCells.push(i);
        }
        return emptyCells;
    };
}
```

Although since you do not declare an isolated scope in your directive (nothing wrong with that), your directive should be able to access the parent scope where you could have left your `getEmptyCells` method. Actually not relying on the parent scope helps keeping your directives modular.

If this fails to work, provide a plunker (or equivalent) example.

EDIT: You really should NOT prefix your own directives with `ng` as those are considered native Angular directives

**EDIT**: I moved your fiddle to plunker as Angular seems to work better there. I posted a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/e11zA8LKvoPTgTqW2HEE
I changed the code to use attributes instead of elements. There seems to be some problems for angular to correctly insert the td's into the row if you are using E instead of A.

EDIT: I changed the syntax `<td get-empty-cells payments="payment">` to `<td get-empty-cells="payment">` for easier usage. You can view the old plunker version (through its interface) for comparison and perhaps help understanding.

Comment: thanks for the above, i tried in my local application and didnt seem to work, here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8hQ3R/13/

Comment: marked your EDIT as the answer as it provides a solution to the question. I have 2 questions however, 1) In the HTML, what does payments="payments" do/represent? 2) In the directive, we have getEmptyCells(payments.Details.length).. Can the contents of getEmptyCells, be passed in through the HTML?

Comment: payment="payments" simply tell the directive that the object payment (right hand side) is passed as an object called payment. I use that as a two-way binding inside the directive and call that.... payment :) <td get-empty-cells="payments" would probably have been easier to understand?) Not sure i understand your second question.

Comment: thanks for the update and explanation. I can successfully display the name and amount, however when i add the line: <td get-empty-cells="payments"></td> i see the following error: Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$compile/tplrt?p0=getEmptyCells&p1= I have checked my directive is present and all names are correct (ive copied and pasted from your plunker)

Comment: That error is displayed when your template won't compile for some reason. I need to see it for me to tell what is wrong, but most often - i find - that i forgot to wrap the template in a single root node. IE. template : '<td>....</td>' is OK but '<td>...</td><td>...</td>' is NOT

Comment: Thanks for the above, you're right, i am seeing that error when the template line is being triggered. Here's is my template line (although its the same as yours): template: '<td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(payments.Details.length)" class="empty">No Payment</td>',

Comment: Replicated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8hQ3R/14/ Open in FireFox with Firebug and can see error in Console tab

Comment: You should double-check that you don't have typos. The template render could? fail if getEmptyCells is not in the scope or payments is null/empty. Did you pass everything correctly? EDIT: Try plunker instead of jsfiddle. The loading order of the script etc is essential for it to work. Plunker has an angularjs template to work from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54639/discussion-between-per-hornshoj-schierbeck-and-oam-psy).

Comment: created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991089/angular-compile-template-error-on-local-project-and-jsfiddle-but-working-fine-i

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data into a directive by reference or value. You have to pass at least getEmptyCells by reference in order to be able to call it. Here is how you do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/8hQ3R/12/

Using directive:

```
<my-empty-cells get-empty-cells="getEmptyCells" payments="payments"></my-empty-cells>
```

Declaring isolated scope with getEmptyCells passed by reference and payments by value:

```
    scope: {
        getEmptyCells: '=',
        payments: '@'
    }
```

**BUT:**

You're going to have problems with this directive template because it has to have single root element and you're having multiple table rows. I would recommend iterating via 1-12 or even months array with ngRepeat and using separate scope function to extract either actual data or empty cell placeholder from model.